# How can i add validation ng-maxlength into ng-repeat with error message?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-validation

I have a simple code :

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="aDiagnosis in diagnosisListForPrescription">

                        <div class="col-md-4 padding-right-zero" id={{aDiagnosis.rowIndex}}>
                            <input class="form-control" name="aDiagnosisName" ng-model="aDiagnosis.Name" ng-disabled="true">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 padding-right-zero form-group" show-errors id={{aDiagnosis.rowIndex}}>
                            <input class="form-control" name="aDiagnosisResult" ng-maxlength="200" ng-model="aDiagnosis.Result" />
                            <p class="help-block" ng-if="form.aDiagnosisResult.$error.maxlength">Too Large</p>
                        </div>
</div>
```

and use $scope.form.$valid to generate the error message.
But problem is since use ng-repeat  every time it finds the same name and when i want to generate second list by clicking a button ,,first error message is gone and error-message now works on the second text (obviously).
So How can i generate error-message each and every time dynamically ,,so every text form in ng-repeat,it has it's own error-message.

Comment: you can proceed this way [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jenrikforlife/Lu4gwxww/)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate dynamically `name` attribute of your inputs in `ng-repeat`. For example, you can put `$index` (or id of your objects or whatever you want) to generate unique `name` for your inputs.

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="aDiagnosis in diagnosisListForPrescription">

     <div class="col-md-4 padding-right-zero" id={{aDiagnosis.rowIndex}}>
          <input class="form-control" name="aDiagnosisName-{{$index}}" ng-model="aDiagnosis.Name" ng-disabled="true">
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 padding-right-zero form-group" show-errors id={{aDiagnosis.rowIndex}}>
          <input class="form-control" name="aDiagnosisResult-{{$index}}" ng-maxlength="200" ng-model="aDiagnosis.Result" />
          <p class="help-block" ng-if="form['aDiagnosisResult-' + $index].$error.maxlength">Too Large</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

[Example on plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/TfKpwxKc6RF2VbVJOz1D?p=preview)

Comment: Tried this way ,,,but same result,,,can u create a plunker,,,,,may be it will helpful for me

Comment: I added link on the plunker to my answer.